# Microsoft login in Xamarin forms - Android App

Tags: android, web, xamarin, authentication, xamarin.forms

After successful login of Microsoft page, Xamarin-forms Android application redirects to the same application’s Web UI instead of Mobile UI.

This issue is quite strange and completely new for us, as this application is already published into Play-Store and works fine until now, we never faced this kind of issues.
We are facing this issue from past one week, (i.e) On our Xamarin- forms Android application we are loading a Microsoft webpage for a login process, on successful login, redirects back to the MobileUI(Homepage). This flow was fine for last 3 years. 
And we are facing this issue recently and working fine with some Versions/Models of devices. We could not able to figure out the RC.
For a reference I am just listing our observations on the test devices with model name and OS version Number.

```
•   Samsung S6 Model-SM-G9201 - Android OS 6.0 - Working model
•   Samsung S6 Model-SM-G9201 - Android OS-7.0 - Not working. Wrongly redirects to Webpage.
•   Redmi Note3 - Android OS-6.0.1 Not Working
•   Samsung SM G920A  Android OS-6.0.1 Not Working
•   ZTE Axon Phone - Android OS-7.1.1 Not Working.   
•   Samsung SM J320A -Android OS-7.1.1 -Working model
•   Gionee s6s - Android OS 6.0 - Working model.
•   Samsung Galaxy A9 Pro - Android OS 8.0 - Not working.
```

All the device models which is mentioned as Not working has the this same application(APK) worked earlier.

Please route us in the correct direction on the resolution. As we do not found any stable RC. 
Whether there is something changed in the Webview to Xamarin forms communication recently, or any phone settings change needs to be done for MS login, or anything changes happens in the Oauth2Autheticator. But we could not able to capture this issue in Debug mode.

Thanks for your time and effort to read this completely.!